Why is Keras pretrained BERT MaskedLM producing inconsistent predictions?
I am trying to use keras-nlp  with a pretrained masked BERT model to predict some tokens in a sequence. However the model produces inconsistent results. What could be wrong or am i misunderstanding something?
import keras
import keras_nlp
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.BertMaskedLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
    "bert_base_en"
)
masked_lm = keras_nlp.models.BertMaskedLM.from_preset(
    "bert_base_en",
    load_weights=True,
    preprocessor=None,
)

test_sequence = preprocessor(["The capital of France is Paris."]) 
outputs = masked_lm(test_sequence[0])
predicted_ids = tf.math.argmax(outputs, axis=-1)

In this example the preprocessor produces the following sequence [101, 1109, 2364, 1104, 1699,  103,  103,  119,  102,0,0,...] with mask positions [5,6,0,0,0,0....]. The predicted_ids are [28059, 18994, 21690, 21690,.....] which is [b'##saur', b'##hetic', b'##lani', b'##lani',....] instead of something remotely close to 'is', 'Paris'.

Apparently the pretrained weights loaded with from_preset() are only for the backbone transformer and the MLM head has to be trained. At least it worked...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
